# C/C++ linux fork() and exec()

Tags: c++, c, linux, multiprocessing

I'm use fork() to create child process. From child process I am use exec() to launch new process. My code as below:

```
   ......
   pid = fork();
   if (pid > 0) {
       WriteLog("Parent Process");
       //Do something
   } else if (pid == 0) {
       WriteLog("Child process");
       int return = execl(ShellScript);
       if ( return == -1 ) 
          WriteLog("Launch process fail");
   } else {
       WriteLog("Can't create child process");
   }
   ......
```

Note: WriteLog function will be open file, write log, and close file. (It is flushed)
      ShellScript will launch new process c/c++.

I run  my program for long run and the code above is called many times. And sometime (rarely) there are problem happen that the new process can't launch successful although the child process is created successfully (I have checked carefully). And one thing is extremely misunderstand when this problem happen that the "Child process" log can't printed although the child process is created successful.

In normal case (there are not error happen) the number of times print the "Child process" and "Parent process" log are the same.

In abnormal case, they are not the same although the child process always create successfully.The "Launch process fail" and "Can't create child process" log aren't printed in this case.
Please help me for consult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) is buffered. Always call `fflush(NULL);` (see [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) for more) before `fork`. Add a `\n`  (newline) at end of every [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) format string (or else, follow them by `fflush(NULL);` ...).

The function [execl(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execl.3.html) (perhaps you want `execlp`?) can fail (so sets `errno` on failure).

```
} else if (pid == 0) {
   printf("Child process\n");
   fflush(NULL);
   execl("/bin/foo", "foo", "arg1", NULL);
   // if we are here execl has failed 
   perror("Launch process fail");
}
```

On error, [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) fails by returning -1 and sets [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) (see also [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) and [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html)). So your last `else` should be

```
} else {
    perror("Can't create child process");
    fflush(NULL);
}
```

You might want to use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) (notably as `strace -f yourprog` ...) to understand the involved [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) (see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...)

Your `WriteLog` should probably use `strerror` (on the `errno` value saved at *beginning* of `WriteLog` ....). I suggest something like

```
 void WriteLog(const char* msg) {
   int e = errno;
   if (e) 
     syslog (LOG_ERR, "%s [%s]", msg, strerrno(e));
   else
     syslog (LOG_ERR, "%s", msg);
 }
```

See [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html).

There are limits on the number of fork-ed processes, see [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_NPROC`  and the bash `ulimit` builtin.

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Comment: I'm sorry for my code is not clearly. I have just updated. I have thinked about fflush everytime write log I also flush. So I have used file to write log. And the log isn't still printed when launch process fail while child process is created successful. (I check this thing based on kill(childid) function

Comment: I will try to use strerror and errno. Current my system also use syslog and log file to print log. I will try use it. Thank you for a good idea.

Comment: At the same time the forked processes are always less than 7. So I think it's not over limit

Comment: the statement `if ( return == -1 )` seems unnecessary: `execl` doesn't return unless it fails.

Comment: The syslog has not still printed when excel launch new process fail although child process launch success. The errno in syslog is always success. It seem to be the system resource is not enough to do anything more :(. I think that :).

Comment: Use `strace` and `gdb`