# Control stdin and stdout of second program (pipes/piping?)

Tags: c++, pipe

I've been wondering how to go about running a program within another program where the the main process can output into the stdin of the secondary process as well as have that second process output to the input to the primary one.

The closest I have come to finding a term for this idea is pipes and forks but I don't quite get the examples i've seen. I've only seen ones where the same program is using pipes to launch itself again. Additionally all of these examples assume that that the programmer is writing/has access to both program's source code.

I would like to be able to interface in this way with programs that are already compiled. Here's an example of what I would like to be able to do:

This is the "compiled" program-

```
 #include <iostream>;
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
       int answer = 42;
       int guess = 0;
       do{
          cout << "Guess a number..." << endl;
          cin >> guess;
          if(guess<answer)
              cout << "Guess Higher!" << endl;
          else if(guess>answer)
              cout << "Guess Lower!" << endl;
       }while(answer!=guess);
       cout << "You win!";
    return 0;
    }
```

This is the "parent" program-

```
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;
int main(){
   //Code executing and connecting the other program
   //while cin/cout would be nice for keeping it clean, other methods of doing this are fine
   //I used cin/cout as placeholders to try and make what I am asking clearer
   String out;
   cin >> out;//Load initial prompt
   int high=100, low=0;
   do{
     cout << (high+mid)/2 << endl;
     cin >> out;//Load response
     if(out.compare("Guess Higher!"))
       low = (high+low)/2;
     else
       high = (high+low)/2;
   }while(out.compare("You win!")!=0);
   return 0;
}
```

The idea here is that my "parent" program could play this game for me. It would make a guess, view the response, use some logic to decide what to do next, guess, repeat until it wins. This particular example is pretty useless but the same general idea of controlling one program with another has a lot of uses. This is just a hypothetical demo of would I would like to be able to do.

Thanks to anyone kind enough to take time out of their day to help.

Comment: Of course you can use this technique to automate and control the input of another program. Do you have any particular questions about it, or are you stuck with a particular problem in implementing such thing you describe? **EDIT:** OK, I think I spotted your concerns. Look up for the [`exec()` function family](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351023/c-c-linux-fork-and-exec) that can be used, to replace the forked child processes executed code.

Comment: What you're asking about is inter-processes communication (IPC). There are a lot of ways to go about it. As an example, you could read/write files or, my personal choice, set up a shared memory area.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm confused with the implementation of this where you have iterative communication instead of a "fire and forget". After reading some another post and sections of you link I believe the idea is you `fork()` to get a nearly duplicate process and the use `exec()` to replace it with the other program. After that I'm not quite sure how the two communicate (how the child knows where it's input/output should be). Will using the pipe made by the parent automatically route the stdin and stdout? Or does something else have to be done for that to happen?

Comment: @Chris _"how the child knows where it's input/output should be"_ stdin, stdout and stderr file descriptors are inherited by the child process, thus the parent and child process can communicate via connecting these using a `pipe()`.