# c++ How to start a process with new stdin and stdout

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I am writing a program in openFrameworks a c++ framework. I want to start another app and communicate with it over stdin and stdout. I can start a new thread conveniently using the ofThread class. I had planned on creating two pipes and redirecting the std in and out of the thread to the pipes (using dup2), but unfortunately, this redirects the pipes for the whole app, not just the thread.

Is there a way I can start another app and be able to reads its output and provide it input?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of another thread you'll need to create a child process using the [`fork()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351023/c-c-linux-fork-and-exec) function (which might involve another thread intrinsically).

The difference is, that fork creates a complete copy of the parent process environment that should be shown on an `exec()` call within scope of the child process, while just `exec()` from a thread tries to share all the resource from it's parent process (thread) and thus might lead to unexpected concurrency (race conditon) problems.

Comment: `exec` from a thread wipes out *the entire process*.  You really must use `fork` first.  (`fork` duplicates only the calling thread into the new process, so you have to make absolutely sure that you don't need any locks in the code that will execute in between `fork` and `exec`.)

Answer (score 0):

If your "another app" is implemented as a subthread within your existing program, you don't *need* to redirect stdin and stdout to communicate with it over pipes.  Just pass the pipe file descriptors to the subthread when you start it up.  (You can use `fdopen` to wrap file descriptors in FILE objects.  If you have `dup2` and `pipe`, you have `fdopen` as well.)

Comment: Is it reasonable to use _pipes_ for such case at all? Or do you still address use of `exec()`?

Comment: The other app is an outside app that can't be integrated

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Pipes certainly *can* be used to communicate between threads, and might be more convenient than anything else, depending on what you're trying to do.  I assumed that an `exec` was *not* involved.  If an `exec` is involved, then your answer is correct.

Comment: @MrBell In that case πάντα ῥεῖ's answer is the right one for you.